# What is the point of having * in a regular expression

Tags: regex

Recently I am thinking the reason why we need a * in regular expression. For example, if we want to represent A0,A1..,Z99, we can do:

```
[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*
```

But `A0A` (which is not we want) is also valid according to the above. What benefit does the * give me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is just a quantifier, matching between zero and unlimited times.

`[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*` matches A0,A1..,Z99 and also A10000,Z123456789...

Remembering that if you dont put the `^` and `$` as anchors, the processor will match the specified part, and return `true` even if the input contain more characters, because you don't said that you want a positive result ONLY if the entire input matches the regex.

If your goal is to match just A0,A1..,Z99, the regex should be:

```
^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]?$
```

Or simply:

```
^[A-Z]\d{1,2}$
```

`\d` means 'digit', and is the same as `[0-9]`.
`{1,2}` means at least 1 time and nothing more than 2 times.
`?` also is a quantifier, matching 0 or 1 time.

Comment: ah..I started to get it, I have just tried with ^ only and $ only, they also match anything. Why is this?

Comment: `^` or `$` alone means you want to match the begin or the end of the input, respectively. And every input has both. So does not make sense a regex with only one of these.

Answer (score 1):

> But A0A (which is not we want) is also valid

No it is not valid, you just need to use anchors:

```
^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*$
```

`^` will ensure this matches at line start and `$` ensures it matches till line end.

Also if only 2nd digit is optional then better to use:

```
^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]?$
```

Since `*` matches 0 or more times whereas `?` matches 0 or 1 time.

Comment: + => 1+ matches
* => 0+ matches

Comment: so, when we say regular expression we always refer to ^some_expr$  ?

Comment: It is safer in most of the cases to use anchors however if you're trying to match multiple matches then **word boundaries** are preferred like `\b[A-Z][0-9][0-9]*\b`

Comment: Also [take a look at this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS3qN3/1) to understand word boundaries better.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to match the strings starts with an uppercase alphabet and the following numbers ranges from 1 to 99.

```
^[A-Z][1-9]?[0-9]$
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end. So this helps to do an exact string match. It won't match at the middle or start or at the end of a string or line. That is, `[A-Z][1-9]?[0-9]` will match `A10` in `fooA10` string but `^[A-Z][1-9]?[0-9]$` won't produce a match in `fooA10` string.

Comment: so, when we say regular expression we always refer to ^some_expr$ ?